# How to correctly handle this situation using GIT? Is it correct put a v2.0 release on a new branch?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-branch

I am not so into GIT and I would like to ask you an opinion about this "work flow" (if it is correct or if I am missing something).

I am working on a software and I have put it on my remote GIT repository (on BitBucket) obtaining a stable version corresponding to the last commit on the master branch.

Then my client has asked me for a pretty heacy change rin this software, I implemented it obtaining a new stable version of my software.

Now I know that I can put it as a new commit on the master branch (and I know that in a second time I can retrieve the old code from it) but I would rather keep the two versions separate (because they basically are different versions of the same application).

So my doubts are:

1) Is it a good idea create a new branch and put this new version on this branch?

2) I created a new branch on bitbucket. What have I to do to put this new version on this branch? I think something like:

```
git add *
git commit -m "Version 2.0 of my application"
git push origin my-new-branch-name
```

Is it correct?

3) If this second release of my software will become the official one can I says to GIT something like: "now the new branch is the master branch and the old master is a side branch?

Comment: This is a very broad topic and it's very hard to give you a concrete answer that says "do this". Instead, you should look into [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: As a comment to your workflow, I would try to stay away from massive commits that correspond to a completely new version because it becomes very hard to troubleshoot things later. Unless your application is miniscule (and then a workflow isn't all that problematic anyway), it is much more common to make many small commits, corresponding to individual fixes or features, and *tagging* the commits that make up the versions you release. Additionally, it is very common to do this kind of development on separate branches, but again, look into *git flow*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your questions:

1. If the software only for one client, it’s not necessary to put changes in a new branch since the released code usually managed in a certain branch. If the software is used for many clients, you should put changes on a new branch in order to meet his/her requirement.
2. Yes, if the new branch is created on bitbucket, you can switch to the branch locally (`git checkout new-branch-name`) and use the commands you showed (`git add`, `git commit` and `git push`). The other way is that you can create new branch locally and push it to bitbucket.
3. Branch names just for you to separate different functions usages. Such as `master` branch as main branch, `develop` branch as developers work for a project, `feature` branch is to develop new features, `hotfix` branch as fix bugs etc. Different teams can make branch names different, such as the main branch usually can be named `main`, `master`, `production` etc.

Comment: Only a last doubt: what do you mean that, creating the branch on BitBucket (I have done in this way), I "can switch to the branch locally and use the commands you showed"?
Have I to do some other operation before commit and push on this branch? Tnx

Comment: After you cloned the bitbucket repo, the current branch is usually `master`, so you should use `git checkout new-branch-name`, and then use `git add .`, `git commit -m 'message'` and `git push origin new-branch-name`.

Comment: mmm but the branch identified by the "new-branch-name" is empty at this time. Doing int this way am I downloading an empty project or what? I'm afraid to overwrite my current project with an empty one on my workspace. What am I missing?

Comment: BTW, can you see the `new-branch-name` branch by `git fetch --all` and `git branch -a`? If you can't see the branch name, that means you didn't create the branch successfully on bitbucket.

Comment: If you created the new branch on bitbucket and did not make changes the this branch now, do not worry, it's always be there. such as you created new branch from `master` branch, then the new branch is point to the same commit with `master`.